# Show progress during file uploading using VolleyMultipart request

Tags: android, android-volley

I am uploading video file to server from android device using VolleyMultipart request. Now I want to show file uploading progress bar with percentage during uploading video file using VolleyMultipart. How can we achieve this functionality?

Below are my code of VolleyMultipart request

```
public class VolleyMultipartRequest extends Request<NetworkResponse> {

    private final String twoHyphens = "--";
    private final String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    private final String boundary = "apiclient-" + System.currentTimeMillis();

    private Response.Listener<NetworkResponse> mListener;
    private Response.ErrorListener mErrorListener;
    private Map<String, String> mHeaders;


    public VolleyMultipartRequest(int method, String url,
                                  Response.Listener<NetworkResponse> listener,
                                  Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, errorListener);
        this.mListener = listener;
        this.mErrorListener = errorListener;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        return (mHeaders != null) ? mHeaders : super.getHeaders();
    }

    @Override
    public String getBodyContentType() {
        return "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);

        try {
            // populate text payload
            Map<String, String> params = getParams();
            if (params != null && params.size() > 0) {
                textParse(dos, params, getParamsEncoding());
            }

            // populate data byte payload
            Map<String, DataPart> data = getByteData();
            if (data != null && data.size() > 0) {
                dataParse(dos, data);
            }

            // close multipart form data after text and file data
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            return bos.toByteArray();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Custom method handle data payload.
     *
     * @return Map data part label with data byte
     * @throws AuthFailureError
     */
    protected Map<String, DataPart> getByteData() throws AuthFailureError {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<NetworkResponse> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            return Response.success(
                    response,
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        mListener.onResponse(response);
    }

    @Override
    public void deliverError(VolleyError error) {
        mErrorListener.onErrorResponse(error);
    }

    /**
     * Parse string map into data output stream by key and value.
     *
     * @param dataOutputStream data output stream handle string parsing
     * @param params           string inputs collection
     * @param encoding         encode the inputs, default UTF-8
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private void textParse(DataOutputStream dataOutputStream, Map<String, String> params, String encoding) throws IOException {
        try {
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
                buildTextPart(dataOutputStream, entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Encoding not supported: " + encoding, uee);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Parse data into data output stream.
     *
     * @param dataOutputStream data output stream handle file attachment
     * @param data             loop through data
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private void dataParse(DataOutputStream dataOutputStream, Map<String, DataPart> data) throws IOException {
        for (Map.Entry<String, DataPart> entry : data.entrySet()) {
            buildDataPart(dataOutputStream, entry.getValue(), entry.getKey());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Write string data into header and data output stream.
     *
     * @param dataOutputStream data output stream handle string parsing
     * @param parameterName    name of input
     * @param parameterValue   value of input
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private void buildTextPart(DataOutputStream dataOutputStream, String parameterName, String parameterValue) throws IOException {
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + parameterName + "\"" + lineEnd);
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes(parameterValue + lineEnd);
    }

    /**
     * Write data file into header and data output stream.
     *
     * @param dataOutputStream data output stream handle data parsing
     * @param dataFile         data byte as DataPart from collection
     * @param inputName        name of data input
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private void buildDataPart(DataOutputStream dataOutputStream, DataPart dataFile, String inputName) throws IOException {
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" +
                inputName + "\"; filename=\"" + dataFile.getFileName() + "\"" + lineEnd);
        if (dataFile.getType() != null && !dataFile.getType().trim().isEmpty()) {
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: " + dataFile.getType() + lineEnd);
        }
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        ByteArrayInputStream fileInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(dataFile.getContent());
        int bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

        int maxBufferSize = 1024 * 1024;
        int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        int bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

        while (bytesRead > 0) {
            dataOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }

        dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
    }

    class DataPart {
        private String fileName;
        private byte[] content;
        private String type;

        public DataPart() {
        }

        DataPart(String name, byte[] data) {
            fileName = name;
            content = data;
        }

        String getFileName() {
            return fileName;
        }

        byte[] getContent() {
            return content;
        }

        String getType() {
            return type;
        }

    }
```

Below code is using for upload file

```
VolleyMultipartRequest volleyMultipartRequest = new VolleyMultipartRequest(Request.Method.POST, mainUrl,
                response -> {
                    try {
                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(new String(response.data));

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                },
                error -> {

                }) {

            /*
             * If you want to add more parameters with the image
             * you can do it here
             * here we have only one parameter with the image
             * which is tags
             * */
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                return parameter;
            }

            /*
             * Here we are passing image by renaming it with a unique name
             * */
            @Override
            protected Map<String, DataPart> getByteData() {
                Map<String, DataPart> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("upload_video", new DataPart("video_name",  uploadFile));
                return params;
            }

            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                String authToken = SharedPreferenceHelper.getSharedPreferenceString(context, SharePrefKey.AUTH_TOKEN, "");
                params.put("Authorization", authToken);
                return params;
            }
        };
        volleyMultipartRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(60000, RETRY_POLICY, BACK_OF_MULTIPLAYER));
        requestQueue.add(volleyMultipartRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by changing this function into below function i shared.

```
private void buildDataPart(DataOutputStream dataOutputStream, DataPart dataFile, String inputName) throws IOException {
    dataByteArray = dataFile.getContent();
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" +
            inputName + "\"; filename=\"" + dataFile.getFileName() + "\"" + lineEnd);
    if (dataFile.getType() != null && !dataFile.getType().trim().isEmpty()) {
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: " + dataFile.getType() + lineEnd);
    }
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

    ByteArrayInputStream fileInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(dataFile.getContent());
    int bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

    int maxBufferSize = 1024 /* 1024*/;
    int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    int bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    long total = 0;

    while (bytesRead > 0) {
        total += bytesRead;
        dataOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        long progress = ((total * MAX_PERCENTAGE) / dataByteArray.length);
        if (lastProgress != progress) {
            FileUploadManager.getInstance().onProgressChange(progress);
            WAAFILogger.d("Buffers", "bufferSize : " + bufferSize + "\n" + "ByteRead : " + bytesRead +
                    "\n" + "buffer : " + buffer + "\n" + "byteAvailable : " + bytesAvailable + "\n" + "maxBufferSize : " + maxBufferSize
                    + "\n" + "progress : " + progress + " byteDataArray :" + dataByteArray.length + "\n" + "total : " + total);
        }
        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    }

    dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
}
```

Comment: This function will actually do the thing you want but the progress will be completed faster than the actual file upload. So for that i have found a solution which you can look at there.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61137778/multipart-file-progress-updating-faster-than-actual-upload/61389287#61389287

Comment: Can you share what changes did you do exactly to this function from that other answer?

Comment: And what the heck is `MAX_PERCENTAGE`?